# Need recommendations of an exception tracking system

Tags: angularjs, angular, exception, coldfusion

We need a recommendation for tracking exceptions in our web app. Our front-end is using Angular 1 or 2, back-end is using ColdFusion. We found [BugSnag](https://bugsnag.com/), but this company cannot do annual billing.

Does anyone know any other similar product?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at the `onError` event in your `Application.cfc`. It allows to report all uncaught exceptions (additionally to the logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Raygun https://raygun.com/, which was very simple to integrate with CF.
I also looked at Rollbar https://rollbar.com/, which was similar.

I highly recommend using something like this, either a SaaS or host your own. It have great gains in efficiency & insight in error detection compared to logs our old emailed alerts.